# How do I output the smallest value entered into an array? (c++)

Tags: c++, arrays

How do I find the smallest value in an array? I think I'm doing it right, but it outputs zero when I run the program.

I did it the same way in another program and it worked. When this runs, the highest element displays, but the lowest displays as zero.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 12;
    double rainfall[ARRAY_SIZE];
    double total_year, monthly_average;
    double highest = rainfall[0];
    double lowest = rainfall[0];

    cout << " Input rainfall for each month: \n" ;

    for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
    {
        cout << " Month " << index+1 << ": " ;
        cin >> rainfall[index];
        total_year += rainfall[index];

        if(rainfall[index] < 0)
        {
            cout << " Rainfall must equal to 0 or higher: " ;
            cin >> rainfall[index];
        }
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++)
    {
        if(highest < rainfall[x])
        {
            highest = rainfall[x];  
        }
        if(lowest > rainfall[x])
        {
            lowest = rainfall[x];
        }
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << endl;

    cout << " There was " << total_year << " inches" ;
    cout <<  " of rainfall this year. \n" ; 

    cout << " The monthtly average was " << total_year / 12 ;
    cout << " inches of rainfall.\n";   

    cout << " The highest rainfall was " << highest << " inches" << endl;
    cout << " The lowest rainfall was " << lowest << " inches" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger.

Comment: @Seyfat Khamidov  The array was not initialized when these variables are declared.   double highest = rainfall[0];
    double lowest = rainfall[0]; So the variables have indeterminate values. You have to initialize the variables after the array will be filled.

Comment: Your total_year variable is not going to be accurate if it tries to increment with rainfall[index] and its lower than 0.  Then you ask the user to enter the new value for rainfall at that same index.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: that should be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare variables where they are used. Otherwise the code will be less readable.

The array rainfall is not yet initialized

```
double rainfall[ARRAY_SIZE];
//...
double highest = rainfall[0];
double lowest = rainfall[0];
```

So using its elements with indeterminate values for the variables `highest` and `lowest` does not make sense.

Declare and initialize the variables just before the loop where they are calculated.

```
double highest = rainfall[0];
double lowest = rainfall[0];

for(int x = 0; x < ARRAY_SIZE; x++)
{
    if(highest < rainfall[x])
    {
        highest = rainfall[x];  
    }
    if(lowest > rainfall[x])
    {
        lowest = rainfall[x];
    }
}
```

In this loop

```
for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
{
    cout << " Month " << index+1 << ": " ;
    cin >> rainfall[index];
    total_year += rainfall[index];

    if(rainfall[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << " Rainfall must equal to 0 or higher: " ;
        cin >> rainfall[index];
    }
}
```

move the statement

```
    total_year += rainfall[index];
```

after the if statement.

```
for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
{
    cout << " Month " << index+1 << ": " ;
    cin >> rainfall[index];

    if(rainfall[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << " Rainfall must equal to 0 or higher: " ;
        cin >> rainfall[index];
    }

    total_year += rainfall[index];
}
```

I would substitute the if statement for a while statement like

```
    while (rainfall[index] < 0)
    {
        cout << " Rainfall must equal to 0 or higher: " ;
        cin >> rainfall[index];
    }
```

but before using the variable `total_year` you have to initialize it

```
double total_year = 0.0;
```

The variable `monthly_average` is not used in the code. So its declaration can be removed.

Take into account that there are the following algorithms in C++ `std::min_element`, `std::max_element`, `std::minmax_element` that can be used to find minimum and maximum alements in an array or other container.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice! but i cant use  std::min_element and others because we havent gone over it in class yet.